# i have argument error when i use devise helper current_user

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

I add `before_action :authenticate_user!` but it isn`t work

repo: https://github.com/d1mentor/robostep

error screenshot:
[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QUsA9.png)

my controller:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # Встроенный в девайз фильтр — посылает незалогиненного пользователя
  before_action :authenticate_user!

  # Задаем объект @user для шаблонов и экшенов
  before_action :set_current_user

  helper_method :user_avatar

  def user_avatar(user)
    if user.avatar_url.empty? then
      avatar_url = "https://i.guim.co.uk/img/media/26392d05302e02f7bf4eb143bb84c8097d09144b/446_167_3683_2210/master/3683.jpg?width=1200&height=1200&quality=85&auto=format&fit=crop&s=49ed3252c0b2ffb49cf8b508892e452d"
    else
      avatar_url = user.avatar_url
    end
  end

  def index

  end

  def set_current_user
    @user = current_user
  end
end
```

My view:

```
<div class="container text-center">
 <div class="row">

    <h2>Моя страница</h2>

    <%= image_tag(user_avatar) %>

</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the screenshot is not to do with the devise helper current_user. It is in regard to the `user_avatar` helper.

In your view, you are calling the method with 0 arguments:

```
<%= image_tag(user_avatar) %>
```

But the method is defined with 1 parameter:

```
  def user_avatar(user)
```

Hence the wrong number of arguments error in the screenshot.